# How to format pattern text export in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm creating an powershell script to format .txt files and eventually be converted to a csv file (unless this can be done together). I've dug through quite a few other questions but haven't been able to figure it out. Every time I run the script below it selects all the data I need but puts it altogether on one line.

```
$importPath = 'C:\Example.txt'
$pattern = "<return>(.*?)</return>"

$string = Get-Content $importPath
$result = [regex]::match($string, $pattern).Groups[1].Value
$result | Out-File -FilePath 'C:\ResponseOnly.txt'
```

I'd appreciate some help in figuring a way to get all the information between the `<return>` and `</return>` but still having all the data broken out on the original rows.

Example of source file:

```
Status: OK
Time Taken: 193
Size: 46511
Timestamp: Thu May 30 03:39:37 MDT 2019
TestStep: getReportResultCsv

----------------- Messages ------------------------------

----------------- Properties ------------------------------
Endpoint: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Username: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
domain: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX HTTP/1.1
Encoding: UTF-8
Password: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

---------------- Request ---------------------------
Request Headers: SOAPAction : ""
Authorization : Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Connection : Keep-Alive
User-Agent : Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
Host : XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Accept-Encoding : gzip,deflate
Content-Length : 378
Content-Type : text/xml;charset=UTF-8


<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
  <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:getReportResultCsv>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <identifier>A0294584B2F933513rt0.c.ie.oF0BBB@5p70B7FsBlEf4v490cAm</identifier>
      </ser:getReportResultCsv>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

---------------- Response --------------------------
Response Headers: Transfer-Encoding : chunked
Server : nginx
Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods : POST,GET,OPTIONS
Connection : keep-alive
Content-Encoding : gzip
Set-Cookie : clientId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
#status# : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date : Thu, 30 May 2019 09:39:37 GMT
Content-Type : text/xml;charset=UTF-8


<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <env:Header/>
   <env:Body>
      <ns2:getReportResultCsvResponse xmlns:ns2="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
         <return>DATE,AGENT GROUP,AGENT NAME,CALLS,HANDLE TIME,Average HANDLE TIME,HOLD TIME,Average HOLD TIME,Average AFTER CALL WORK TIME
2019/04/04,Billy Bob,Joe Joseph,6,04:15:53,00:42:39,00:00:00,00:00:00,00:01:55
2019/04/05,Billy Bob,Joe Joseph,14,04:39:26,00:19:58,00:47:53,00:03:25,00:02:20
2019/04/06,Billy Bob,Joe Joseph,11,06:33:13,00:35:45,00:17:21,00:01:35,00:04:30
2019/04/07,Billy Bob,Joe Joseph,13,05:47:06,00:26:42,00:02:03,00:00:09,00:02:27
2019/04/08,Billy Bob,Joe Joseph,11,03:20:21,00:18:13,00:00:03,00:00:00,00:02:44</return>
      </ns2:getReportResultCsvResponse>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Example of how file should be:

```
DATE,AGENT GROUP,AGENT NAME,CALLS,HANDLE TIME,Average HANDLE TIME,HOLD TIME,Average HOLD TIME,Average AFTER CALL WORK TIME
2019/04/04,Billy Bob,Joe Joseph,6,04:15:53,00:42:39,00:00:00,00:00:00,00:01:55
2019/04/05,Billy Bob,Joe Joseph,14,04:39:26,00:19:58,00:47:53,00:03:25,00:02:20
2019/04/06,Billy Bob,Joe Joseph,11,06:33:13,00:35:45,00:17:21,00:01:35,00:04:30
2019/04/07,Billy Bob,Joe Joseph,13,05:47:06,00:26:42,00:02:03,00:00:09,00:02:27
2019/04/08,Billy Bob,Joe Joseph,11,03:20:21,00:18:13,00:00:03,00:00:00,00:02:44
```

Comment: please post at least a few lines from the source file, how they look with your code ... and how they **_should_** look. right now there is no realistic way to even make a guess about what is or isn't working as you want. [*grin*]

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Lee_Daily I have always used stack overflow for researching things, but first time asking a question. Still new to powershell..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easier then you expect, since what you have for input is XML. Try this:

```
$importPath = 'C:\Example.txt'
[xml]$DataIn=Get-Content $importPath
$DataIn.Envelope.Body.getReportResultCsvResponse.return| Out-File -FilePath 'C:\ResponseOnly.txt'
```

That will just get you what you're looking for.

If you really want to use RegEx, I would read the whole file in as a multiline string, and match against that to get your output. You just need to tell the RegEx that you're going against a multiline string when you do it.

```
$pattern = "(?ms)<return>(.*?)</return>"
$string = Get-Content $importPath -raw
$result = [regex]::match($string, $pattern).Groups[1].Value
$result | Out-File -FilePath 'C:\ResponseOnly.txt'
```

Comment: thanks for looking at this with me, when I run this I get the error: Cannot convert value "System.Object[]" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "The specified node cannot be inserted as the valid child of this node, because the specified node
is the wrong type."

Comment: Yeah, seeing the whole input file it makes sense to do it with a RegEx match or replace. Glad we could get it worked out for you.

Answer (score 1):

_[
edit - i missed the post by TheMadTechnician. [*sigh ...*] i will leave this here just in case the minor differences help the OP a bit.

edit 2 - TheMadTechnician pointed out that using the `-Raw` parameter for `Get-Content` was unneeded in this case. removed that and added the needed `-split` to make a proper fake `Get-Content` data set.
]_

here's one way to get that data into a CSV. since it is valid XML, you can use the `[xml]` type accelerator to convert it from text to an XML object. then you can navigate the XML to the place where the csv data is. once you are there, you can feed that to the `ConvertFrom-CSV` cmdlet to make an array of objects.

then, *finally* [*grin*], you can export that nice, neat array to a CSV file with `Export-CSV`.

here's the code ...

```
# fake reading in a text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$InStuff = @'
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <env:Header/>
   <env:Body>
      <ns2:getReportResultCsvResponse xmlns:ns2="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
         <return>DATE,AGENT GROUP,AGENT NAME,CALLS,HANDLE TIME,Average HANDLE TIME,HOLD TIME,Average HOLD TIME,Average AFTER CALL WORK TIME
2019/04/04,Billy Bob,Joe Joseph,6,04:15:53,00:42:39,00:00:00,00:00:00,00:01:55
2019/04/05,Billy Bob,Joe Joseph,14,04:39:26,00:19:58,00:47:53,00:03:25,00:02:20
2019/04/06,Billy Bob,Joe Joseph,11,06:33:13,00:35:45,00:17:21,00:01:35,00:04:30
2019/04/07,Billy Bob,Joe Joseph,13,05:47:06,00:26:42,00:02:03,00:00:09,00:02:27
2019/04/08,Billy Bob,Joe Joseph,11,03:20:21,00:18:13,00:00:03,00:00:00,00:02:44</return>
      </ns2:getReportResultCsvResponse>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine

$IS_XML = [xml]$InStuff
$ReportResult = $IS_XML.Envelope.Body.getReportResultCsvResponse.return |
    ConvertFrom-Csv

# on screen
$ReportResult

# to CSV
$ReportResult |
    Export-Csv -LiteralPath "$env:TEMP\TaylorGreen_-_ReportResult.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

truncated screen output ...

```
DATE                         : 2019/04/04
AGENT GROUP                  : Billy Bob
AGENT NAME                   : Joe Joseph
CALLS                        : 6
HANDLE TIME                  : 04:15:53
Average HANDLE TIME          : 00:42:39
HOLD TIME                    : 00:00:00
Average HOLD TIME            : 00:00:00
Average AFTER CALL WORK TIME : 00:01:55

[*...snip...*] 

DATE                         : 2019/04/08
AGENT GROUP                  : Billy Bob
AGENT NAME                   : Joe Joseph
CALLS                        : 11
HANDLE TIME                  : 03:20:21
Average HANDLE TIME          : 00:18:13
HOLD TIME                    : 00:00:03
Average HOLD TIME            : 00:00:00
Average AFTER CALL WORK TIME : 00:02:44
```

csv file file content ...

```
"DATE","AGENT GROUP","AGENT NAME","CALLS","HANDLE TIME","Average HANDLE TIME","HOLD TIME","Average HOLD TIME","Average AFTER CALL WORK TIME"
"2019/04/04","Billy Bob","Joe Joseph","6","04:15:53","00:42:39","00:00:00","00:00:00","00:01:55"
"2019/04/05","Billy Bob","Joe Joseph","14","04:39:26","00:19:58","00:47:53","00:03:25","00:02:20"
"2019/04/06","Billy Bob","Joe Joseph","11","06:33:13","00:35:45","00:17:21","00:01:35","00:04:30"
"2019/04/07","Billy Bob","Joe Joseph","13","05:47:06","00:26:42","00:02:03","00:00:09","00:02:27"
"2019/04/08","Billy Bob","Joe Joseph","11","03:20:21","00:18:13","00:00:03","00:00:00","00:02:44"
```

Comment: Yours is explained very well, but from the looks of his comments on my answer I don't think he has valid XML, just the snippet that he provided happened to be valid XML. Also, converting to CSV, then exporting CSV eats a lot of cycles. I'd try just dumping the raw text to a file before I used `ConvertFrom-Csv` and `Export-Csv` to try and sanitize the data. True, it won't have quotes, but most things don't care, and some things prefer not to have them. But kudos on the explanation, and actually using the right key words where I lacked both of those. Last thing, I don't think you need `-raw`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician - thanks! [*grin*] i suspect that you are correct about the OP having _something_ other than what is shown. [*sigh ...*] as for the `*-CSV` cmdlets ... i wanted to present a fairly simple solution. those two cmdlets do a lovely bit of work - IF the input is clean. ///// you are correct that the `-Raw` is unneeded ... i will go back and fix that. thanks for the heads-up! [*grin*]

Comment: @TheMadTechnician & Lee_Dailey Thanks for the help both of you, I didn't put the whole file in originally because I was trying not to flood the page with info and basically show the issue, but I've edited the original post to show the original file in case it helps.

Comment: thanks for posing the updated info! that makes it clear that _my_ solution aint going to work. [*grin*] the one by TheMadTechnician should work, tho. ///// mine would work IF i ran a `-split` on the two returns surrounding the CSV data.